# How to swap textfields position on screen - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have two UITextFields and want to swap their position when a button is clicked. Perhaps also animate the swap.

i.e.:

textFieldOne & textFieldOne are positioned with AutoLayout using Interface Builder.

On Button Click

- Get textFieldOne position parameters,
- Get textFieldTwo position parameters
- Set textFieldOne position parameters to textFieldTwo,
- Set textFieldTwo position parameters to textFieldOne

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code. Do you know how to get the current position of the buttons? Do you know how to set the frame of a button? What have you tried? What issue are you having?

Comment: You mention a `UITextField` in your title and a `UIButton` in your example. Please edit your question to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: And add some details. Do you want to animate the swap?

Comment: Even though @DanielStorm gave a great answer to start I edited for clarification. Now I'm looking to animate the swap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simply swap positions of your `UITextField`'s you can assign their `origin` values to each other.

```
// Store textFieldOne's postition
let tempPos : CGPoint = textFieldOne.frame.origin
UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
// Set textFieldOne to textFieldTwo's position
textFieldOne.frame.origin = textFieldTwo.frame.origin
// Set textFieldTwo to textFieldOne's original position
textFieldTwo.frame.origin = tempPos
UIView.commitAnimations()
```

Or, for a more *Swift* way of doing things you can use a [Tuple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) to swap the values without the need for any temporary variables.

```
UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
(textFieldOne.frame.origin, textFieldTwo.frame.origin) = (textFieldTwo.frame.origin, textFieldOne.frame.origin)
UIView.commitAnimations()
```

Comment: The Swift way in simply beautiful. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel.. I am using the same solution but within a cellForRowAt indexPath but doesn't work. Any catch here?

Comment: @LohithKorupolu probably not referencing the correct instance as cells are reused.

Answer (score 1):

In the function that receive the button click you will need to save the position of each button and transfer the other:

Swap position:

```
let positionButton1 = button1.frame.origin
let positionButton2 = button2.frame.origin

button1.frame.origin = positionButton2
button2.frame.origin = positionButton1
```

Swap positions and size:

```
let positionButton1 = button1.frame
let positionButton2 = button2.frame

button1.frame = positionButton2
button2.frame = positionButton1
```